# Strange warning message: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r, sqldf

I found a strange behaviour of sqldf - it issues "NAs introduced by coercion" warning when a variable exists with the same name as a column and different data type. The following code:

```
x <- structure(list(euring = c(12380, 12430), species = c("Locustella luscinioides", 
"Acrocephalus schoenobaenus")), .Names = c("euring", "species"
), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

species <- structure(list(EURING = c(0, 980), Species = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_
)), .Names = c("EURING", "Species"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

require(sqldf)

result <- sqldf("
select species as Species
from x
")
```

produces:

> Warning message: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

and `result` then contains only NAs.

If variable `species` didn't exist, everything is OK. But `sqldf` shoudln't even touch the variable `species`, right??

**EDIT:** I suspect it is a bug. I reported it: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/issues/23

Comment: Running that exact code does not give me the warning message. Have you tried restarting your R Session?

Comment: @Shique wow! I tried to open a new session and no warning issued!! I don't get it. How is this possible??

Comment: A probable cause would be that some `options()` were set that aren't default. But it can be something else for all I know.

Comment: I was not setting any options. It can't be in the data either, because I initialize them very simply as you see. There must be something rotten in either R or sqldf!

Comment: @Shique I found it! The problem was that there was a data.frame called `species`!! But `sqldf` shouldn't even touch it, right? Please see the updated question.

Comment: This was cross posted to https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/issues/23 and answered there.

Answer (score 2):

It's curious. But you can solve it by referring to the table in the query.

```
> sqldf("select species as Species from x")
  Species
1      NA
2      NA
Warning message:
In asfn(rs[[i]]) : NAs introduced by coercion
> sqldf("select a.species as Species from x a")
                     Species
1    Locustella luscinioides
2 Acrocephalus schoenobaenus
```

There is a bug when `method` is null. `method = data.frame` is another option.

```
> sqldf("select species as Species from x", method = data.frame)
                     Species
1    Locustella luscinioides
2 Acrocephalus schoenobaenus
```

Comment: interesting, thanks! Anyway, I suspect that the sqldf behaviour is a bug, I reported it.

Comment: Yes, is a bug. I have traced the problem and there is an error in the `method`. Fixing method is also fixed.

Comment: thanks @Juan. How comes that every time I have so much work and I'm in time pressure I have to deal with a bug where it's least expected? ;/

Comment: you are welcome to comment on the issue in GitHub: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/issues/23